# Routing and Parameters in Vaadin flow

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I see many questions pertaining to query and route parameters. Somehow each new flow and parameter resolutions seem to be a mystery just as soon as I think I have mastered them.

I have two flows, MainView and a DisplayView
My MainView has a `setParameter(BeforeEvent beforeEvent)` thats like this

```
  private void doGridSetup(BeforeEvent event) {
    id  = id.isEmpty() ? event.getRouteParameters().
                                get("id").orElse(""): id;
    if (!id.isEmpty()) {
        Optional<BlappityBlahDTO> blappityBlah = getBlappityBlah(id);
        if (!blappityBlah.isEmpty()) {
            setAllFields(blappityBlah);
            try {
                event.rerouteTo(DisplayVeiw.class,
                        prepRouteParameters(id, blappityBlah.get().getBlahID()));
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace(System.err);
                //HACK HACK HACK.. doesn't work anyways
                UI.getCurrent().navigate(DisplayView.class, prepRouteParameters(id,
                        blappityBlah.get().getBlahID()));
            }
        }
        binder.bindInstanceFields(this);
    }
}

RouteParameters prepRouteParameters(String id ,String blahID) {
    RouteParam idParam = new RouteParam("id", id);
    RouteParam blahParam = new RouteParam("blahID", blahID;
    RouteParameters routeParameters = new RouteParameters(  idParam, blahParam);
    return routeParameters;
```

}

```
    @Route("blappity/display/:id/:blahID")
    @Slf4j
   public class DisplayView extends VerticalLayout
        implements BeforeEnterObserver, BeforeLeaveObserver, HasUrlParameter<String> {
```

Doesn't seem to matter if I try `event.reroute` or `UI.getCurrent().navigate()`, my `DisplayView` never gets displayed and the error I see is 'Navigation target 'com.blappity.blaha.DisplayView' requires a parameter.'
I am not sure what's going on anymore.

`Java: 17.0.6`
`Vaadin: 24.1.1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are two flaws in your code.

1. If you are using route templates `@Route("blappity/display/:id/:blahID")`, hence RouteParameters, you should not implement `HasUrlParameter` and override `setParameter`. Instead you should take those parameters in beforeEnter or afterNavigation.
2. If you want to forward the user with new parameters, you should note that `rerouteTo` does not update the URL, but forwardTo does. So if you use `beforeEnter`, you can use `forwardTo`. If you move the code to `afterNavigation`, you should use normal `ui.navigate(..)` instead, as when `afterNavigation` runs, the previous navigation cycle is complete.

IMHO the best practice is just to store the url parameters to class field in `beforeEnter`, and do the actual `Grid` setup and fetching data in `afterNavigation`. Say you have view based access control, you do not want to fetch anything from database before navigation cycle is complete.

Comment: HasUrlParameter is called once. AfterNavigation gets called every time I navigate to a child component. Setting up the UI or fetching data in the parent every time I navigate to a child component does not sound optimal.